# How to prevent linefeed when hit enter on Firefox OS mobile phone

Tags: javascript, firefox, mobile, keycode, firefox-os

I want to use the return key to submit something.
How do I prevent linefeed.
I don't want to produce something like '\r' or '\n'.

I used the code like:

```
if(e.keyCode  == 13){
    if(textContent != ""){submit();}
    //e.preventDefault();
    //e.stopPropation();
    e.returnValue = false;
    return false;
}
```

I don't want to make a new row.

Comment: Wait, you want the Enter key to *make a new row*, or *to submit something*?

Comment: I don't want the Enter key to make a new row.

Comment: Why don't you just use a single-line text input box?

Comment: We need to use a textarea to do more

Comment: How are you going to enter a new row in that textarea, ever?

Comment: Why would you comment `e.preventDefault()`? That seem to be the right track.

Comment: e.preventDefault();It doesn't work.BTW,using "return false" is the same as using "e.preventDefault"

Comment: @nneonneo using"ctrl"+"Enter",but that's no the point

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good (you don't need the e.returnValue), but you have to use it on a keydown event, not a keyup.

Comment: Did it solve your problem? Let me know if you still have an issue.